# How to play .3gp videos in mobile using RTMP (FMS) and HTTP?

Tags: mobile, video-streaming, flash-media-server, flashlite

I am not able to play video on mobile device which is .3gp container and H.263 / AMR_NB encoded. I just want to play my website videos in mobile device also just like youtube.com. I want to use RTMP and HTTP both. My requirement is as follows-

Which codec and container will be best?

Should I use FLV to play video on mobile device?

RTSP required or can be use RTMP?

Is NetStream and NetConnection methods different from Flash Player in Flash Lite Player?

How to play 3gp video using RTMP stream ie. ns.play(“mp4:mobilevideo.3gp”, 0, -1, true) is it ok or any thing else required?

For mobile browser and computer browser, can I use single player or I have to make different player for computer browser and mobile browser?

It would be better if I can do it with single player for both mobile and computer browser.

Sample code required for testing. If you can.

I got below article in which they mention that we can play video 3gp container in mobile also. Please find the article.

Articles URL-

http://www.hsharma.com/tech/articles/flash-lite-30-video-formats-and-video-volume/
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/dmotamedi_fms3.html

Thanks 
Sunil Kumar

Answer (score 1):

We've established that it's possible to play mp4 within a 3gp wrapper, but only if the file has an mp4 extension, and for Flash 9 onwards.

See http://www.adobe.com/eeurope/products/hdvideo/faq/

Answer (score 0):

> > Hi I am not able to play video on mobile device which is .3gp container and H.263 /AMR_NB encoded. I just want to play my website videos in mobile device also just like youtube.com. I want to use RTMP and HTTP both. My requirement is as follows-
> >
> > Which codec and container will be best?
> >
> > Should I use FLV to play video on mobile device?
> >
> > RTSP required or can be use RTMP?

.flv is not supported on all devices that support FL 3.0. Please refer to the following threads in the nokia discussion forum:http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?p=731458#post731458 regarding transcoding in 3gp to be used in the rtsp server. 
You can use http for flv.

> > Is NetStream and NetConnection methods different from Flash Player in Flash Lite Player?

I have no clue about this.

> > How to play 3gp video using RTMP stream ie. ns.play(“mp4:mobilevideo.3gp”, 0, -1, true) is it ok or any thing else required?

For the rtsp, you need to setup the darwin streaming server, which is pretty simple to install and then place your 3gp/mp4 files there. There is no need for a netstream object for this. You can simply use the 'play' method with the instance of the video object:

.play(<3gp_Or_mp4__file>);

> > For mobile browser and computer browser, can I use single player or I have to make different player for computer browser and mobile browser? It would be better if I can do it with single player for both mobile and computer browser.

No clue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to look at the 3gp players official website at http://www.3gp-player.com .
You can read and get some information about playing 3gp video files on both Desktop/Laptop computers, and cellphones/mobile devices.
Most of the tools offered there are free, and so is the information about all the 3gp player / converters.

Hope this helps you.